# How to use Elasticsearch search functionality using Spring Boot framework and the insertion is made through MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a Spring boot application which uses MongoDB to store the documents. Now, I want to add the searching functionality to my API using Elasticsearch. How will I do this and how will MongoDB and Elasticsearch sync with each other? I am using Maven as the build tool.

Comment: Dear Neekhil, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to avoid frustration and increases chances of your questions being answered. Most of "I want a new feature" questions are either too broad or opinion based which is off-topic here.

Comment: Why have you decided to use Elasticsearch for searching?

Comment: Mongodb already has data. Why do you not want to search from mongodb itself?

Comment: Hi Boris, I am using elasticsearch because it gives faster search results as compared to MongoDB.

Comment: Also, I want to have real-time searching